# Stripping out a piece of text string from a column in Python using REGEX

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas, dataframe, split

I need to strip out the date and time string from a column in a data frame that has rows of uneven delimiters i.e. some with three and some with four commas.

I am using Python3, pandas

Example:

```
df['sample field'].head(2)
```

returns

```
"4294-Skateboard Foundation (MSF) Advanced Rider Course (ARC) , 1134123 , Oct 24 2016 12:00AM ,"
"1254-Skateboard Foundation (MSF) Experienced Rider Courses (ERC/BRC 2) , 3217121 , May 15 2015 12:00AM ,"
"4457-Total Control, Level 1 (Advanced Skateboarding Clinic) (TCL1) , 6743468 , Nov 11 2013 12:00AM ,"
```

Intended Return

```
"4294-Skateboard Foundation (MSF) Advanced Rider Course (ARC) 1134123"
"1254-Skateboard Foundation (MSF) Experienced Rider Courses (ERC/BRC 2) 3217121"
"4457-Total Control Level 1 (Advanced Skateboarding Clinic) (TCL1) 6743468"
```

I am trying to figure out how to strip the date and time values: on the back, if the text strings into a new column: Intended Returned.

To do the reverse I used the following:

```
df3_1['Date'] = df3_1['Course ID'].str.extract('([A-Za-z]+\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+:[0-9A-Z]+(?=\s+\,+))')
```

This worked extremely well in stripping off the date but I am now trying to find out how to keep the text without the date.

Comment: is the comma at the end part of the string? i cant seem to find multiple delimiters here as u can pick this off by ```rsplit``` on the ```,```. easier if u shared the dataframe of two rows, with ur expected output in dataframe format as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Text':['4457-I only, need, this, Nov 11 2013 12:00AM ,',
                 '2359-I only need, this, Apr 11 2013 12:00AM ,']})

#get rid of the date section and merge the rest on whitespace
df['extract'] = df.Text.str.strip(',').str.split(',').str[:-1].str.join(' ')

df
            Text                                           extract
0   4457-I only, need, this, Nov 11 2013 12:00AM ,  4457-I only need this
1   2359-I only need, this, Apr 11 2013 12:00AM ,   2359-I only need this
```

Comment: it worked fine for this one: "4294-Skateboard Foundation (MSF) Advanced Rider Course (ARC) , 1134123 , Oct 24 2016 12:00AM ,"                                      
 ---but not the one below
====================================================
"1254-Skateboard Foundation (MSF) Experienced Rider Courses (ERC/BRC 2) , 3217121 , May 15 2015 12:00AM ,"

Comment: this seems much better as an example. could u add it to ur question, with expected output

Comment: point taken! Thanks, I edited the question to reflect a better picture.

Comment: i just ran it with current code and it comes out as u posted. what does it return when u run it?

Comment: I am using VS CODE and it is strange. For some reason some of the 4294s are okay. The other ones still show the date on the end.  Changing .str[:-1] to 1 seemed to fix it however it stripped off the numbers: which are not needed anyway. I am just trying to figure out what does that piece do.

Comment: interesting. ```[:-1]``` is supposed to get the strings and exclude the last entry. changing to 1 is essentially ```str[0]``` which is the first entry after the split. anyways, hope u get to solve the problem and understand it better.

Comment: I am going to accept this answer as it is correct with the exception of that weird tweak, but that will be relative to whoever needs it.

Answer (score 0):

Assumed you already have the date column

```
df['Course ID'].replace(regex=r'(?i)'+ df.Date,value="")
0    4457-I only, need, this,  
1      2359-I only need, this, 
Name: Course ID, dtype: object
```

Comment: Hi YOBEN, I tried this solution and I am getting the following error: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "DatetimeArray") to str.   QUESTION: why would I be trying to concatenate the blank Date value back on when all I am trying to do is remove the date value out?